# Can Darth Vader read minds like Kylo Ren?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, star-wars

In the movie *Star Wars Force Awakens*(Ep-VII), we have seen that Kylo Ren can get into people's mind.

In the movie *Star Wars A New Hope*(Ep-IV), Darth Vader uses a machine to read mind from Princess Leia.

Is there any where mentioned in other comics or side stories that Darth Vader is capable of getting into other people's mind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, yes. Darth Vader can also read minds like Kylo Ren.

This has been shown in *[The Return of the Jedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi)*.

When there is fight between Darth Vader and Luke on Death Star in front of Emperor, Darth Vader says this,

> VADER: Give yourself to the Dark Side. It is the only way you can save your friends. Yes, your thoughts betray you. Your feelings for them are strong. Especially for... sister. So, you have a twin sister. Your feelings have now betrayed her, too. Obi-Wan was wise to hide her from me. Now his failure is complete. If you will not turn to the Dark Side... then perhaps she will...

Here he was able to read Luke's mind. Though, it appears to me that Kylo Ren has greater skills to read minds.

Comment: this leads to another question, why did he use the probe to get intel in Leia from episode 4

Comment: In-universe: because torture's fun! Out-of-universe: because that power hadn't been contrived by the scriptwriter yet.

Comment: Also I think, they are not strong enough to get into a female's mind!!!!! they didn't succeed for neither Leia nor Rey.

Comment: @anvesh.veerelli I am not sure about male or female, because I only watched original trilogy, Rogue One and Force Awakens and didn't read any books.

Comment: Darth readed Luke minds without being close to him and while his force was concentrated on fight. Also Darth didn't had some force abilities due to his lack of limbs. And Luke was trained to some extend in force concentration.  Also if Kylo is better than Darth it mean that Ren is some pretty uber Jedi being able to read Kylo's mind without any training.